# Как правильно: нет межей или меж?

Tags: орфография, морфология

1) Для существительных ж. рода 1-го склонения характерно нулевое окончание в форме Р.п. мн. числа: **стЕны — стен, зЕмли — земель.**

2) В то же время существуют исключения (например, нет ***свечей***).  Но слова ***межа*** я среди исключений не нашла (в Грамматике-80), а в парадигме Зализняка указана форма ***меж*** (за правильность Зализняка я больше не ручаюсь, возможно, это "неправильный" Зализняк).

3) В текстах (старых и достаточно новых) форма ***межей*** используется:

Уже и не отличить было поля от **межей**, сцепились так ― не оторвать. [Валентин Распутин. Последний срок (1970)]

Они кочевали с гуртами скота по степям и перелескам и не знали границ и **межей**. [С верой и надеждой (2001) // «Жизнь национальностей», 2001.11.23]

**И вопросы:**

Какая форма (меж или межей) считается правильной в современном языке?

Какие ещё сущ. 1-го склонения ж. рода в виде исключения имеют окончание ЕЙ в Р.п. мн.числа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Какая форма (меж или межей) считается правильной в современном языке?

За правильность А. Зализняка всегда можно ручаться, другое дело, что нельзя ручаться за правильность фальшивок. В моём "Грамматическом словаре" А.Зализняка 1980 г. издания (это не фальшивка) указано, что допустимы оба варианта: **меж** и **межей**.

> Какие ещё сущ. 1-го склонения ж. рода в виде исключения имеют
>   окончание ЕЙ в Р.п. мн.числа?

Ещё есть **праща** (пращ обозначено как устаревшее), **обжа** (единица площади), **вожжа**, **свеча** (но *игра не стоит свеч*). В словаре не сказано, что это исключения, просто обозначена другая парадигма склонения.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.  Насколько я знаю, Зализняк только первые 100 тыс. слов обработал вручную, а остальное - это машинное творчество. Если попадется неверная форма, то я не знаю, сайт ли это фальшивый или машина дала неверный результат (соответственно, я всегда могу рассчитывать получить минус за любой из этих вариантов). Вожжи - известное слово, не знаю, почему его нет в Грамматике. Там есть еще простыня - простынь и простыней. В любом случае, спасибо за ответ. А как насчет частотности форм меж и межей? Мне форма "меж" кажется странной.

Comment: Ага, тогда ещё *ноздря — ноздрей*. А с частотностью это сложно. В распространённых частотных словарях учитывают все парадигмы слова, а результатам поисковиков в таких вопросах нельзя доверять. К тому же ещё предлог **меж** будет искажать картину.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.